# Prove that, for vector fields, $[X,Y]=0$ implies $[X,[Y,Z]]=0$ for all $Z$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I want to prove this claim : If $[X,Y]=0$, then for any tangent field $Z$, $[X,[Y,Z]]=0$

I try to do this by using local coordinate.

$$
X=\sum_{n=1}^{m}a_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\space\space\space,
Y=\sum_{n=1}^{m}b_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\space\space\space,
Z=\sum_{n=1}^{m}c_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\space\space\space$$

Then,
$$
[X,[Y,Z]]=\sum_{t=1}^{m}(\sum_{s,k=1}^{m}
a_s\frac{\partial b_k}{\partial x_s}\frac{\partial c_t}{\partial x_k}+
a_s b_k\frac{\partial^2 c_t}{\partial x_s\partial x_k}-
a_s\frac{\partial b_t}{\partial x_k}\frac{\partial c_k}{\partial x_s}-
a_s\frac{\partial^2 b_t}{\partial x_s\partial x_k}c_k-
\frac{\partial a_t}{\partial x_s}b_k\frac{\partial c_s}{\partial x_k}+
\frac{\partial a_t}{\partial x_s}\frac{\partial b_s}{\partial x_k}c_k)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_t}
$$

However, I couldn't make any progress.

Comment: Jacobi identity states that $[X,[Y,Z]] = [Y,[X,Z]]$ in case $[X,Y] = 0$. In your coordinates system, Swcharz lemma says $\partial_{s,k}=\partial_{k,s}$. That can be useful

Comment: Take $X=\partial/\partial x$ and $Y=\partial/\partial y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If the claim is true then for any $Z=Z^1 \partial_x +Z^2 \partial_y$ we have $Z^1_{yx} = Z^2_{yx} = 0$, which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result isn't true without additional conditions. For example in $\mathbb{R^3}$, take $X=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, Z = xy\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. Then $[X,Y] = 0$, but $[X,[Y,Z]] = [X,x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}] = \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\ne 0$.